# Difference between S3 and Redshift (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am studying first time about Amazon Web Services. I want to know what is the **difference or relation** between Amazon s3 and Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/) is storage service.Amazon S3 a simple web services interface to store and retrieve any amount of data from anywhere on the web. With Amazon S3, you pay only for the storage you actually use.

[Amazon Redshift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/getting-started/) is a fast, fully managed, petabyte-scale data warehouse.

Amazon Redshift gives you fast querying capabilities over structured data using familiar SQL-based clients and business intelligence (BI) tools using standard ODBC and JDBC connections. Queries are distributed and parallelized across multiple physical resources.

The relationship between Redshift and S3 is that data can be pumped into your warehouse from s3. More instructions can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html).